# Angular Material Toolbar Breadcrumb Presentation

Tags: angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I'm new to designing with Angular Material and I'm trying to figure out breadcrumb spacing in the toolbar. Here's where I'm at...

[image: Angular Material Breadcrumb Mark-Up]

[image: Angular Material Breadcrumb Presentation]

The question I'm hoping to get answered is:
Is there a 'correct' way to do breadcrumbs like this in the latest version Angular Material or do I need to introduce custom CSS correct the alignment issues?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no direct UI component available in angular material for breadcrumbs. Creating a custom directive would be a right way of doing this  in angular way instead of custom css.

Answer (score 0):

you can just use css & flexbox to achieve that:

```
<h1 class="my-breadcrumb">...</h1>

.my-breadcrumb {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```